# Airflow failed task restarts automatically

Tags: airflow

I am facing a bug in case where a task marks itself as failed after retrying for the max number of retries. And then the task restarts itself and marks itself with running. This interferes with the next run of the same task as sometimes they both run in parallel.

Comment: Please post a snippet of code illustrating the configuration of your task and the configuration of the Airflow instance.